# Cognos 10.2.2 as400 iSeries DB2 jdbc connection

Tags: jdbc, dynamic, db2, ibm-midrange, cognos

I attempted to set up the jdbc connection to as400 iSeries DB2 for Dynamic Cube features...

However the creation connection doesn't work out and returning error message :

XQE-DS-0020 "DB2 UDB for AS/400" server version "6.1" is not supported

I have placed in the jt400-6.4.jar in both 
1.\webapps\p2pd\WEB-INF\lib
2.\v5dataserver\lib
and restarted my server..

still no luck..

Answer (score 1):

With 10.2.2 the version supported is 7.1 and 7.2.

[Check this specs.](http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/prereqsForProduct?deliverableId=1391013543612#!)

Comment: Thanks for the information. 
i am looking at the sheet.. but isnt stated 10.2.2 support 6.0 and 7.0? 
i assume that it should support 6.1..
so meaning i need to download any version of iSeries db2 Jar file..
please correct me if i am wrong...

Answer (score 0):

To use JT400 driver you must be using IBM Cognos 10.2.1 FP3 or higher. DB2 version must be 7.1 or above and that is why the connection is rejected and states that it is because the version is not supported by the Dynamic Query engine.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27037784
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27042164